# An array of structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, structure

For the life of me I can't figure out the proper syntax for creating an array of structures in C. I tried this:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
} foo[][] = {

    {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 4, 5 },
        { -1, -1 }
    },

    {
        { 55, 44 }
        { 100, 200 },
    }
};
```

So for example foo[1][0].x == 100, foo[0][1].y == 5, etc. But GCC spits out a lot of errors.

If anyone could provide the proper syntax that'd be great.

**EDIT:** Okay, I tried this:

```
struct foo {
     const char *x;
     int y;
};

struct foo bar[2][] = {

     {
      { "A", 1 },
      { "B", 2 },
      { NULL, -1 },
     },

     {
      { "AA", 11 },
      { "BB", 22 },
      { NULL, -1 },
     },

     {
      { "ZZ", 11 },
      { "YY", 22 },
      { NULL, -1 },
     },

     {
      { "XX", 11 },
      { "UU", 22 },
      { NULL, -1 },
     },
};
```

But GCC gives me "elements of array bar have incomplete type" and "excess elements in array initializer".

Comment: If your compiler is giving you errors, you'll get better answers if you post the exact error messages that you are getting.

Comment: You shouldn't have a comma after the last element.  In your declaration of foo bar, you have 5 extra commas.

Comment: @kk6yb: commas after the last element is allowed in C because it really helps out when code is auto generated by another program.  It also helps us people out when we remove the last element in a struct, union, enum, or array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This creates and initializes a two-dimensional array of structures, with each row containing three.  Note that you haven't provided an initializer for the `array[1][2]`, which in this case means its contents is undefined.

```
struct foo {
    const char *x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    struct foo array[][3] = {
        {
            { "foo", 2 },
            { "bar", 5 },
            { "baz", -1 },
        },
        {
            { "moo", 44 },
            { "goo", 200 },
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Made x pointer to const string.  Try to make your examples close to your real code.

Comment: Thanks. Still can't get it to work on my end though (replace int x with const char *x above, and then change the initialization accordingly from int (eg 55 above) to "foo"... GCC spits out a ton of "excess elements in array initializer" errors).

Comment: There's an extra comma after { 100, 200 }

Comment: Look at Matthew's `struct foo array[][3]` and at your `struct foo bar[2][]`.  Fix that and your edited question should work.

Comment: @kk6yb: That's probably okay.  Trailing commas are a very widely accepted extension and became canonical in C99.

Comment: Actually, trailing commas in initializers are standard C89.  It's only enums that previously didn't allow it.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. Got it to work... turns out in array[][3], 3 should be the max number of elements you'll be using (e.g, if you added "blah" after "foo"/"bar"/"baz" you'd have to change 3 to 4).

Comment: It's not actually the maximum, it's the exact width of the row.  As I said, the initializer is too short the contents of the extra locations will be undefined (for stack variables).

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest approach would be to split up the struct and array declarations:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    struct foo foo_inst = {1, 2};
    struct foo foo_array[] = {
        {5, 6},
        {7, 11}
    };
    struct foo foo_matrix[][3] = {
        {{5,6}, {7,11}},
        {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}}
    };

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that nested array declarations in C (and C++) cannot have arbitrary length for any array except the outermost.  In other words, you can't say `int[][] arr`, and you must instead say `int[][5] arr`.  Similarly, you can't say `int[][6][] arr` or `int [][][7] arr`, you would have to say `int[][6][7] arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is the declaration of the array.
you can only leave the first square-bracket set empty. the rest have to be explicitly declared.

so instead of this:

```
struct foo bar[2][]
```

you should do this:

```
struct foo bar[][4]
```

This is really the first thing to sort out.